# Outlook Cached mode on Terminal Server

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-terminal-services, outlook-2003, outlook-2010

How can I get Outlook 2003 to work on Terminal Server in cached mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot enable cached mode in any Outlook version prior to 2010 on a Terminal Server. Please see the following Microsoft article for details:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-2003-resource-kit/considerations-when-installing-outlook-in-a-terminal-services-environment-HA001140268.aspx

Comment: You can enable cached mode in Outlook 2010 on a RDSH (or TS). (I realize that the question and the article you linked is relevant to Outlook 2003, but I just wanted to add this for completeness).

Comment: Happy to add my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2003 and 2007 don't have an option to enable cached mode.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a blog entry that describes how to enable an OST on Outlook 2003

http://davidoverton.com/blogs/doverton/archive/2007/07/28/how-to-enable-cached-mode-for-outlook-when-used-inside-terminal-server-which-means-that-bcm-can-work-too.aspx

> OK, this is in response to the people who have posted on this subject.
>   Someone was kind enough to give me the exact details, but I shall
>   protect my sources except to say they know the insides of MS tools
>   well.
>
> The warning here is that this is unsupported and could completely
>   destroy your users profiles, so only do this is you are comfortable
>   editing the registry
>
> The short description:
>
> Open up Regedit
>
> navigate to [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
>   Messaging
>   Subsystem\Profiles\\13dbb0c8aa05101a9bb000aa002fc45a]

[image]

> Find the key 00036601     (REG_BINARY) - note the number in it now so
>   you can undo the changes if needed
>
> Change the value to one of the following
>
> •enabled value;  84 01 00 00  - note that on my desktop system the
>   enabled value is 84 19 00 00, so play around with this a little
>   •enabled with Public Folders/Favorites: 84 05 00 00 •disabled value;
>   04 00 00 00

[image]

> FYI - you will need to search for "00036601" and adjust ALL of them
>   since each key is for a different user on your system.